# How do I get rid of the action bar?

Tags: android, sdk

Alright so I've tried practically every method possible. I've developed a Image Button to open a new activity but it had the title of something I didn't want.

The usual method:

```
android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitleBar">" >
```

But it comes up with an Error.

What do I do???

Whole Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="saintbedeslytham.saintbedes" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".event"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_event" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.event" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "title of something I didn't want" - That Title is the name of your app.

Comment: Post your entire `AndroidManifest.xml`. What is "practically everything possible?"

Comment: Your AppTheme must extend a base theme that has no action bar.  `<style name="Theme.MyCustomTheme.NoBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to have the default look without the action bar?

Comment: Check your AppTheme declaration in the styles.xml file, and do the modification as I mentioned above

Comment: Ok applying the method now...

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations Zsolt Boldizsar,
The method works!

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Copying the the AppTheme Declaration and replacing the .DarkActionBar with .NoActionBar worked!

Comment: Glad that I could help. Cheers